# MS Release Management Powershell DSC Downstream Builds

Tags: c#, release, continuous-deployment, ms-release-management, continuous-delivery

I am using TFS2013 & MS Release Management vNext to provide some continuous deployment capability to the development team, but am struggling to find a feature (or a way of achieving the capability) related to downstream (or chained) builds.

What I would like to achieve is the ability to start another build upon successfully completing another.

The basic premise behind this is we would *sometimes* have services that need to be deployed before a web application is subsequently deployed, but not in all cases (otherwise the build itself would simply deploy all of these components every single time) - in 80% of cases the web application will be deployed in isolation.

Has anyone achieved this in any other way than custom TFS build templates? Is there actually an un-documented feature somewhere in MS RM?

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly then you want to deploy to an environment based on some pre-condition being met. There is a nice story for that with new release management pipeline see the video below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPuWRL4jORQ

Comment: Pretty much, a serial build scenario. We are looking into RM2015 now which does seem to include this feature, thank you.